# Can a message be sent to a batch of tokens to FCM clients using the Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I would like to send a message to a batch of devices by using their tokens because I have different reciever groups that are quite dynamic and can change. I have my groups defined on the backend Spring Boot server and the Message.Builder has only a "setToken" method. Does this mean that i have to loop through all of the tokens to send the message?

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [sending messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) suggests that you need to use [MulticastMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MulticastMessage) for that.

```java
// Create a list containing up to 100 registration tokens.
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
List<String> registrationTokens = Arrays.asList(
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
    // ...
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n"
);

MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
    .putData("score", "850")
    .putData("time", "2:45")
    .addAllTokens(registrationTokens)
    .build();
BatchResponse response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(message);
// See the BatchResponse reference documentation
// for the contents of response.
System.out.println(response.getSuccessCount() + " messages were sent successfully");
```